# Kann man Sprachen, Dialekte, usw. kleinschreiben?

Tags: spelling

Aus Heinrich Bölls Roman *Ansichten eines Clowns*:

> Anna ist aus Potsdam, und schon die Tatsache, daß wir, obschon evangelisch, rheinischen Dialekt sprechen, kommt ihr irgendwie ungeheuerlich, fast widernatürlich vor.  Ich glaube ein Protestant, der **bayrisch** spräche, würde ihr wie der Leibhaftige vorkommen.

Warum ist *bayrisch* kleingeschrieben? Ich glaubte, man könnte (etwa) *bayrisch aussehen* (was auch immer das bedeuten würde [z.B. Dirndl tragen]), weil da *bayrisch* ein Adverb ist. Aber wenn man es spricht, dann bezieht sich mach natürlich auf eine Sprache (Dialekt, usw.).

Comment: Ich glaube, die Frage basiert auf einem Misvertändniss, http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/deutsch

Comment: Oder andersrum: Bayrisch ist ein Adverb und wird in deinem Beispiel auch als solches benutzt. Der Protestant könnte genausogut *laut* oder *leise* sprechen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Endlich gibt jemand zu, dass ich der Leibhaftige bin … Allerdings ist die Aussage auch grob vereinfachend, in Augsburg leben ca. 15 % evangelische Christen, in Regensburg 13 % in Kempten (Allgäu) waren es lange Zeit zwischen 15 und 20 % und von Kaufbeuren habe ich keine Zahlen gefunden, sie sollten aber ähnlich hoch sein. Dass der Anteil der Katholiken so hoch ist, erklärt sich durch Zuzug aus dem Umland, alle Städte sind seit der Reformation evanglisch. Aber das nur am Rande.

---

*Bayrisch* ist natürlich eine Falschschreibung, richtig wäre *bairisch*, wenn die Dialektgruppe gemeint ist, oder *bayerisch*, wenn ein Bezug zum Bundesland Bayern hergestellt werden soll. Die Frage dreht sich aber um die Großschreibung im Zusammenhang mit *sprechen*.

Das *bayrisch* im Satz beschreibt nicht das, was der Protestant spricht, sondern die Art, *wie* er spricht. Er könnte auch laut, unverständlich oder mürrisch sprechen. In jedem Fall handelt es sich um ein Adverb, und Adverbien werden klein geschrieben. Deswegen ist es richtig, *bairisch sprechen* klein zu schreiben.

Comment: Danke fürs Edit und für die Antwort. Nur wüste ich nicht, ob er auch eigentlich Deutsch mit bayrischen Akzent gesprochen haben könnte (dabei meine ich nicht, dass Heinrich Böll das hätte meinen können, aber  kontextunabhängig).

Comment: @c.p. *Bairisch sprechen* impliziert eigentlich zunächst den Dialekt, muss es aber nicht. Es kann auch nur ein Akzent sein. Das geht aus dem Kontext nicht ausreichend hervor.

Comment: Lt. Duden geht auch bayrisch.